# Pulse Radar using Barker code

Tags: matlab

i am trying to build a pulse radar using barker codes. i modulate the barker code and sine wave and added some noise as well. then i attached a matched filter whose parameters are shown in the image. and then made an attempt to demodulate, which i don't think is right.
can someone please help me with the matched filter- like are the coefficients right?
and also what else can i add remove and demodulate/detect.

Comment: Replace your barker code generator with a phase-coded waveform block, and select the option to enable matched filter coefficient output. You need a transmitter, receiver, and narrowband Tx/Rx arrays. You need a phased array toolbox free space channel for Tx to target and target to Rx, a target block, two platform blocks (one for target and one for ownship), and a range angle block. These have a specific order in which they should be positioned, and if you need help doing that, you can respond with questions. Once you have all of these things set up, you can then use a matched filter.

Comment: @Baddioes i have to build a basic radar which includes modulate/demodulate and matched filter. the aim of my project is to study phase coded waveforms, their doppler tolerance. so can you help me in this way? also i have version 2019a and in phase coded block i cant find any option to enable matched filter coefficient o/p. should i get 2023 version?

Comment: @ian You are still defining the matched filter incorrectly. The signal you are transmitting is not the series of +1 and -1 of the Barker code. You have a pulse that is encoded with them. Remember that the pulse has some pulse width, and inside that, each value of -1 and +1 is there for some time within the pulse. All of those values are your signal. The matched filter is then the time-reversed conjugate of your signal. You should really look at some examples and do this in MATLAB itself and not Simulink as it hides a lot of the details needed to learn this well.

Comment: @Envidia i created a matlab function block which fetches coefficient of matched filter. the code being `function coeff = fcn()
waveform = phased.PhaseCodedWaveform('Code','Barker',...
    'ChipWidth',1e-5,'NumChips',4,...
    'OutputFormat','Pulses','NumPulses',1);
coeff = getMatchedFilter(waveform);
end ` then i connected it to matched filter coefficient input. am i doing it right?

Comment: @ian barker codes are easy to set matched filter coefficients, they are either + or - 1. You can look them up online. All the blocks I listed are necessary for your project. You cannot evaluate doppler performance if you do not have a target that has a non-zero radial velocity. Put all of the blocks I mentioned into simulink and see if you can hook them up properly. If you have specific questions you can ask. It may be worth it to upgrade to 2023 if 2019 can’t do what you need, but I bet it can be done in 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a disconnect between what the Barker code itself is, and its nominal autocorrelation function, to how you actually use it to modulate a signal.

When using Barker codes in a radar system, you're *modulating* (aka encoding) some transmitted pulse of pulse length $\tau$. This pulse will then have N-chips, or subpulses, inside of it that correspond to each -1 or +1 of the Barker code.

Of course, taking for example the Barker-13 code's series of -1 and +1, performing the autocorrelation does give you the expected result. But in a real system, you don't just have the thirteen individual -1/+1 floating around, you have a no-kidding real signal that you transmit/receive to process. Using a very-low frequency carrier to show how a pulse is modulated, a Barker-13 coded pulse looks like this (real part):

[image]

The red-orange parts correspond to the -1 and blue to the +1 in the corresponding Barker code. If you modulate this down to baseband, then you would get:

[image]

*These* are the signals you would use to define the matched-filter, either at baseband or some intermediate frequency. It is *not* the thirteen -1/+1 of the Barker code. If you take the proper matched filter (the time-reversed conjugate) and apply it, you get the same response for both:

[image]

Which is the response expected.